# React native claims that my picture does not exist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I try to import a picture from assets folder in a way that was already working in the same project, but I get error claiming that this file does not exist, but after pasting the file path from error message in file explorer the picture opens up.

```
const marker = require('../../assets/markers/city.JPG')
```

After moving the files around for some time I am out of ideas why RN cannot see the file.

Comment: Maybe case sensitive name?

Comment: Try `import {imageName} from '../../assets/markers/city.JPG'`
And use it like `<Image source={imageName} style={style} />`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I figured out that the problem derives from the `.JPG` which should be `.jpg` (in my case was `.PNG` and after I changed it to `.png`,  it worked! )